# Listing model files in BIM360 through data management API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I have a need to display models stored in BIM360 in the Forge Viewer. For this reason I'd like to list all models that are contained in a project.

I was looking at fetching them using the  [search API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-search-GET/). Is this a reasonable way to do it? I guess the only way to identify model files is to use attributes.fileType in the filter? And then look at the relationships.derivatives data. Or is there some other way to search for models?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your request is not supported by the Search API currently. With my experience, extracting `relationships.derivatives` out is the only way manually from the API responses that contain this attribute e.g.

- [GET projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-contents-GET/)
- [GET projects/:project_id/items/:item_id/tip](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-tip-GET/)
- [GET projects/:project_id/items/:item_id/versions](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-versions-GET/)