# In a Revit add-on .net dll List the available BIM 360 Projects then the available BIM 360 Models to open

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api

In my Revit add-on I would like to write a command that I can open multiple BIM 360 models. I have 10 models to open in a project to work on simultaniously each morning. I have a command that will open multiple models from a network location. However I would like to write a similar command that will open the cloud models. It will save me loads of time. They can be all opening while I make coffee.

1. Using .net how can I get a list of the available projects to use in a new dialog I can create.
2. Once the project is selected, get a list of the available models to open.
3. Open the models in Revit.

If there is a browser dialog solution, sure it will be better, but please it needs to be very simple to simply list & open the models in Revit.

```
        Dim OpenOptions As New OpenOptions
        Dim ModelPath As ModelPath = ModelPathUtils.ConvertCloudGUIDsToCloudPath(ModelPathUtils.CloudRegionEMEA, projectGuid, modelGuid)
        commandData.Application.OpenAndActivateDocument(ModelPath, OpenOptions, False)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

These two topics have been discussed here in the past, e.g.,
in [listing model files in BIM360 through data management API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54943886/listing-model-files-in-bim360-through-data-management-api).
You can find many more related discussions by searching, e.g.,
for '[list bim360](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=list+bim360)'.

Those solutions are cloud based, so they cannot be addressed using the pure Windows desktop Revit .NET API.
Therefore, the browser-based approach that you yourself suggest might be a good starting point for this first step of listing the available models.

The second step is to open the BIM360 models in Revit once you have determined their paths.

This was addressed in May last year by The Building Coder in the note
on [locally opening RVT file managed by BIM360](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2020/05/using-referenceintersector-with-a-linked-file.html#3),
and here on StackOverflow in the question
on how to [open Revit BIM360 model via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57806330/open-revit-bim360-model-via-command-line). Things are in flux in this area, though, and may have changed since then.

The safest way to achieve this currently is also to use the web-based Forge API.

Native Revit API functionality supporting the opening of a BIM360 hosted model directly in Revit on the desktop is in the works but not ready quite yet, I'm afraid.

Here are some notes from previous related conversations that I have not yet gotten around to editing and publishing:

Processing BIM360 model:

Question: As much a BIM M360 as a Revit question:
I’m programming some Revit desktop plugins using pyRevit/Python, and I’m trying to automate the linking of Revit files that live within BIM360.
For example, I’d like to be able to open a file from one BIM360 project and copy it to another BIM360 project (including all of the linked files), and then re-path all of the links in the copied model to read from the new project.
There are a number of other interactions I’m looking at as well, but that’s the biggest hurdle at the moment.
We’re working in Revit 2019, with eyes toward 2020, if that helps get to the bottom of things.

Answer: One little part of the task you address is discussed here,
on [opening a BIM360 model via the desktop command line and the Revit API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57806330/open-revit-bim360-model-via-command-line).
Maybe the same approach can be used to handle the linking as well.

Stepping back a bit, what kind of Revit file are you targeting?

A Revit model may be stored in BIM360 in three ways:

- Revit cloud worksharing
- File based and uploaded to BIM 360 directly
- Desktop connector

Ad 1: There is no API to access #1. You can publish to BIM 360 using forge API. But currently, you cannot set the same environment through api.

Ad 2: You can use forge API to upload and download.

Ad 3: No Desktop connecter API, but I believe you can use normal Windows API for the part that copies files within folders.

We may still need to do a bit of research.
But something we need to look into separately one by one.
Could you clarify on these?

Response: I think I’m using the models based on #1 above, although I’m not 100% sure if I have my terminology correct.
Essentially, we’re hosting our files on BIM360 (the old C4R way of doing things, whatever it’s called now) and uploading the workshared model through Revit.
We’re then interacting with it from there.
I have a feeling that that description probably confuses things even more, but hopefully not.
In a broad sense, our idea is to have a ‘library’ of pieces of buildings (RVT files) living on a cloud server somewhere.
We’d then have an interface that allows users to select various configurations of those library pieces, and the tool would copy those pieces into a new project and automatically link them together based on some rules built into the tool.
We have a working version of the tool for workshared models on our own internal servers, but we’d prefer it in the cloud – specifically, Autodesk cloud services, since they are meant to deal with Revit files.
Not sure if that made things clearer, or muddied the waters even more.

You might also want to study the article by Eason Kang on [BIM360 Docs: Setting up external references between files (Upload Linked Files)](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/bim360-docs-setting-external-references-between-files-upload-linked-files).

Finally, to wrap up, the complete working sample implementing
a [desktop app to view models on hubs (BIM 360 or Fusion Team)](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-viewhubs-desktop) might
fulfil a large part of your requirements right out of the box.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I ran the the sample:
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-viewhubs-desktop it worked once on my desktop and I celebrated, but since then I recive an error that is beyond my knowledge to fix: I wish I could find a very simple 'Hello Forge' desktop sample.

Comment: Well, that should be no problem. Many samples are on GitHub: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge; step-by-step tutorials are available on the main web page: https://forge.autodesk.com

Comment: I've been working for a few years on this, I got a little closer and managed to create an accessToken. I've added a reference Autodesk.forge.dll to my project and located it in the same folder as my dll. and I updated some references. However now I am stuck again with 'Could not load file or assembly Autodesk.Forge.'

Comment: Dim hubs As Object = Await hubsApi.GetHubsAsync